# How to select random groups of similar records?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have following table:

```
create table users (
  id serial primary key,
  gender text not null,
  age integer not null
);

insert into users (gender, age)
select (case when i % 2 = 0 then 'male' else 'female' end), (i)
from generate_series(20, 45) i;
```

I need function(s) that will be able to fetch `n` random groups of `k` users. One user may appear in more than one group (so there might be two identical groups in the result group list). I need four variants (or four functions) of such function:

1. users within one group are picked randomly
2. users within one group are picked randomly but they should be of same gender (gender for a single group should be picked randomly)
3. users within one group are picked randomly but they should be within same age range (difference between their ages should not be > 5 years)
4. Combination of 2) and 3) (same gender + same age range).

I've used word "should" because if there are no users that match required conditions then random users should be picked within group.

Also `k` (size of each group) does not have to be dynamic (in fact it will be `2` or `3`). Performance here is very important. I know that `order by random()` might be a bottleneck and I am considering adding column `rnd integer` to users table that will be updated periodically.

---

As for point (2) I have something like this - it works but I don't know yet how to "fallback" when there are not enough users with specific gender in database.

```
with genders as (
  select (case when random() > 0.5 then 'male' else 'female' end) as gender
  from generate_series(1, 10) i
)
select (
  select json_agg(row_to_json(three_users.*))
  from (
    select *
    from users u
    where u.gender = g.gender
    order by random()
    limit 3
  ) as three_users
) user_group
from genders g
```

And here is what I have for point (3) (assuming user ages in database between 18-50):

```
with ages as (
  select
  floor((random() * (50 - 18) + 18)) age
  from generate_series(1, 10) i
)
select (
  select json_agg(row_to_json(three_users.*))
  from (
    select *
    from users u
    where u.age >= (a.age - 5) and u.age <= (a.age + 5)
    order by random()
    limit 3
  ) as three_users
) user_group
from ages a
```

---

And here is what figured out for "fallback" users so far:

```
with ages as (
  select
  floor((random() * (50 - 18) + 18)) age
  from generate_series(1, 10) i
)
select (
  select json_agg(row_to_json(three_users.*))
  from (
    select *
    from (
      (select u.*, true as primary
      from users u
      where u.age >= (a.age - 5) and u.age <= (a.age + 5)
      order by random()
      limit 3)
      union
      (select u.*, false as primary
      from users u
      order by random()
      limit 3)
    ) six_rows
    order by six_rows.primary desc
    limit 3
  ) as three_users
) user_group
from ages a
```

Comment: What did you already implement from these?  Is there a particular point where you got stuck?

Comment: @dezso: I've updated my question. This is what I have so far, but I guess it might not be optimal way since in the last example there are 4 nested selects...